# Something similar to LaTeX's \include command in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, latex

With LaTeX, you can use the `\include` command to include files in the document so that they are directly linked; and the main document, when compiled, will always use the updated version of those documents.

Now I know that obviously Microsoft Word documents are not compiled, but is there a similar functionality that allows you to have included files in your main document that is auto-updated (ie whenever the file is read) whenever the included file changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the {INCLUDETEXT} field function. The manual process is described [here](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001316_Linking_Word_Documents.html) for example.

Remember to update your fields before printing or exporting (there's an option for that).